# Prove that there exists at least one element $f$ in $S_4$ such that $f$ cannot be expressed as $g^4$ for any $g\in S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Given that $S_4$ is the set of all permutations on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Prove that there exists at least one element $f$ in $S_4$ such that $f$ cannot be expressed as $g^4$ for any $g\in S_4$.

So if I construct a function $\mathcal{F}:S_4\to S_4$ and show that this is not surjective, then the problem will be solved. But I cannot construct such a function. Any assistance would be helpful.

**Addition:** Since $S_4$ is finite, we can also prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is not injective which will imply that $\mathcal{F}$ is not surjective.

Comment: I do not see how constructing a non-surjective function $S_4 \to S_4$ even remotely solves anything.

Comment: @MarkSaving If such a function can be constructed which is not surjective, then obviously there will exist a $g\in S_4$ whose pre-image won't exist in $S_4$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Although this was my attempt towards the problem. It may not be correct.

Comment: I think you would do much better to look at the possible ways of writing an element of $S_4$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @RobArthan There would be $4!$ permutations. Which one should I consider?

Comment: I said ways of writing an element as a product of disjoint cycles: there are only the following forms: $(a), (a\;b), (a\; b)(c\;d), (a\;b\;c)$ and $(a\;b\;c\;d)$. You can now verify that the forms $(a\;b)$ and $(a\;b(c\;d)$ are not fourth powers.

Comment: @RobArthan I got your point. What would be $f$ in this case?

Comment: $f$ could be any permutation that can be written as a product of disjoint cycles of the form  $(a\;b)$ or $(a\;b)(c\;d)$ (i.e., a transposition or the product of two disjoint transpositions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function $$ F:S_4 \to S_4$$ as $$ F(f)=f^4$$
The function F is not injective because for example for $$f=(1,2,3,4)$$ we have $$F(f)=id$$ and $$F(id)=id$$ where $id$ is the identity function $$id(x)=x$$
Thus $F$ is not surjective as well and we are done.

Comment: Finally something that recognized my attempt.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I really like this answer. @ManjoyDas note that it isn't sufficient to construct **a** function that isn't surjective. You have to show that $g \mapsto g^4$, in particular, is not surjective!

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis can't we say that if $f$ is not one-one on a finte set $S$, then it is not surjective? An informal proof is always possible by a diagram.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Of course you can. But finding just one function that is not surjective/injective doesn't solve your problem. I was referring your original attempt in which you stated that you need to construct a function that is not injective/surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the types of factors your permutations can have: You can have identity, you can have a transposition $(a,b)$, you can have triplets $(a,b,c)$ or a last $(a,b,c,d)$.

Now, clearly $(a,b)^4 =1$, $(a,b,c)^4 = (a,b,c)^3(a,b,c) = 1(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b,c,d)^4 = 1$.

So $S_4^4$ consists solely of permutations of the form $(a,b,c)$ and the identity.

Comment: Can you please explain $(a,b,c)^4 = (a,c,d)^3(a,b,c) = 1(a,b,c)$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas That was of course an error. It’s of course $(a,b,c)^4=(a,b,c)^3(a,b,c)$.